# Best way to use accessToken API to get an access token

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

What is the best way to use accessToken API to get an access token?
Can we call it multiple times via different threads? is there any threshold for this API?

Comment: Can you post documentation to what you are referring to?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html

Comment: You should be able to retrieve one access token and use across multiple API calls for its lifetime (the `expires_in` attribute).

Comment: is there any limit if I call accessToken API multiple times ?

Comment: just you overall API limit. Why do you think you need to call the access token API multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Requesting auth token this frequently is not advisable, and indicates a fundamental flaw with your integration architecture. Since you are asking for the *Best way to use accessToken API to get an access token*, I will give you my recommendation:

As Bryan indicates in his comment, you should be looking at the `expires_in` attribute of the response returned from the endpoint:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiJYM3ZRaWY4NUhKTXlKSHZUTllKaXk4ZVEiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJqMmM5bnc5aWxwcDBjNDRyM2ViaGNtaGUiLCJlaWQiOjUxMDAwMDEzNywic3RhY2tfa2V5IjoiUzUwIiwicGxhdGZvcm1fdmVyc2lvbiI6MiwiY2xpZW50X3R5cGUiOiJTZXJ2ZXJUb1NlcnZlciIsInBpZCI6MzQyfQ.Os6CPeyiQJRHJm0LAzY2gkxz2_r6SfDjGZQnToeidjE.6CGqFMwpo_7te7tOQB0XN1dxBg7wM3qpTYAY7vLrTZWb7JJbpO7oA27PWql7ipI_DJV_tfR5lLSnAMZLELUMAi4lslOKu5NoiAOfIdnQLcPu2eFca5ehIljes6QonPK4wlh6Vtc-tFACFyzx2XLb1tICXTbUr5aWg5D6q",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1072,
    "scope": "email_read email_send email_write sms_read sms_send sms_write",
    "soap_instance_url": "https://example.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/",
    "rest_instance_url": "https://example.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"
}
```

It displays, in seconds , expiration time of the token provided which will be approximately 1080 seconds, or 18 minutes. The actual access token lifetime is 20 minutes, but the `expires_in` setting is 18 minutes because it is recommended that you refresh your token two minutes before its lifetime ends.

In the system you are using for integrating with SFMC, you should store the token value, along with the timestamp on which it is to be refreshed. Each time you are to use the token for authenticating an API call, you will check the locally stored value, and unless the refresh time has been reached, use the local value - otherwise, you can do a single call to fetch an updated token.