# Max number of valid access tokens per client

Tags: marketing-cloud, accesstoken

We have observed that if you call SFMC Auth API in succession, you get different access token each time and all are valid till expiry.

I wanted to know if there is some upper limit on number of valid access tokens per client. In our use case we want to maintain one access token per machine. Will there be an issue with scaling?

For reference Auth API:

```
POST https://{YOUR_SUBDOMAIN}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "account_id": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer here, to see some best practices around this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/393221/36623

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of a v2 access token is **20 minutes**. Read [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html)

I cannot find any official documents mentioning about REST API call limit. But it seems the Salesforce Support suggests [not using more than 2,500 calls per minute](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/205901/83900)

Comment: …but why would you want to flood the auth endpoint with token requests, for a token with 20 minute lifetime

Comment: I did not say he should flood the auth token , just provide information for his consideration